# SkyDrive for iOS: keeping user logged in

Tags: ios, onedrive

I use SkyDrive on my iOS app, everything works fine until I close my app and when I open it again I have to authenticate user again. I use this code:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.clientID = @"my id";
        self.scopes = @[@"wl.signin", @"wl.skydrive", @"wl.skydrive_update"];

        self.liveClient = [[LiveConnectClient alloc] initWithClientId:self.clientID
                                                           scopes:self.scopes
                                                         delegate:self
                                                        userState:@"initialize"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

This is for sign in user first time, when I click on the button:

```
- (void)signInFromViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (_liveClient) {
        if (self.liveClient.session == nil) {
            [self.liveClient login:viewController
                        scopes:self.scopes
                      delegate:self
                     userState:@"signin"];
        }
    }
}
```

And LiveAuthDelegate method;

```
- (void)authCompleted:(LiveConnectSessionStatus)status
          session:(LiveConnectSession *)session
        userState:(id)userState
{
    if ([userState isEqual:@"signin"]) {
        if (session != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Signed in");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Auth error");
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do else? Maybe something in authCompleted method when userState is initialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had almost exactly the same issue. The solution was to add the "wl.offline_access" scope to my initial login call.

Source code and other details can be found in the question I posted, which is here:

[iOS OneDrive (skydrive) app displays permissions dialog every time it runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354546/ios-onedrive-skydrive-app-displays-permissions-dialog-every-time-it-runs/22394970#22394970)

Hope this helps!

Diz